# MonacaのPersonalプランで利用できるアプリ内課金プラグインはありますか？

Tags: javascript, monaca, アプリ内課金

Monacaを利用したAndroidアプリにアプリ内課金機能を開発しようとしています。

MonacaライセンスはPersonalなのですが、
利用できるCordovaプラグインはありますでしょうか？

もし上記が不可能であれば、
上のライセンスで利用できるプラグインを教えていただけますでしょうか？

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。ご教示お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Personalプラン**では**Cordovaプラグイン組み込み**は出来ません。
[料金プラン一覧](https://monaca.mobi/ja/pricing)に出来ることが記載されております。
それ以外となるとMonacaが提供しているプラグインしか設定できません。
Monacaの提供しているプラグインのリストの中に課金の仕組みを実現できるものは無かったかと思います。

Monacaにて外部プラグインの導入を検討するのであれば**Goldプラン**以上のアカウントである必要があります。
おそらく`Cordovaプラグイン`か`PhoneGapプラグイン`のどちらかと入れることになるかと思います。
プラグイン導入に関してはMonacaのサポート範囲外ですのでCordovaの知識を多少なり身につける必要があるかと思います。